# How can my Core Module export another Module?

Tags: angular, module, angular5, angular-module

I have 3 modules.

- CoreModule
- FeatureModule
- ViewModule

My `CoreModule` provides singleton services and components to the rest of the app. It like my `ShareModule`, except everything in it should be a singleton.

I have my `FeatureModule` inside of my `CoreModule`. I want my `CoreModule` to export my `FeatureModule` so that my `ViewModule` can use the components and service from the `FeatureModule`.

`Feature  -->  Core` THEN `Core --> AppModule THEN`App--( provide feature)--> View`

I currently have it set up like this. Currently the FeatureComponent is not recognized in the ViewModule.

FEATURE MODULE

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    SharedModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    FeatureComponent,
    FeatureDialogComponent,  
  ],
  exports: [
FeatureComponent,
FeatureDialogComponent,
  ],
 providers: [
 FeatureService,
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    FeatureComponent,
    FeatureDialogComponent,
   ],
 })
export class FeatureModule { }
```

CORE MODULE

```
@NgModule({
     imports: [FeatureModule],
     declarations: [],
     exports: [FeatureModule,],
     providers: [],
})
```

VIEW MODULE

```
 @NgModule({
     imports: [],
     exports: [],
    providers: []
  })
  export class ViewModule {}
```

APP MODULE

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        CoreModule,    <-----Core module imported
        SharedModule,
        AppRoutingModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Show us your ViewModule?

Comment: @Zircon & Evrett, I update that mistake. View Module is now there.

Comment: You might need to import your FeatureModule into your ViewModule.